# Microsoft.Ace.OLEDB.16.0

Tags: excel, database, vba, macos, ms-access

Can anyone please help me understand why Microsoft.Ace.OLEDB.16.0 doesn't work on Windows 10 x64 with Office 2016 x86?
I get runtime error  `-2147467259 (80004005)` when the connection to `OLEDB 16.0` is opened using the following code:

```
Public Sub ValidityDateCheck_SRT_Templates()

NameFile = "x"

    sConn = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0;WSS;IMEX=1;RetrieveIds=Yes;" & _
        "DATABASE=" & sSHAREPOINT_SITE & ";" & _
        "LIST=" & sDEMAND_ROLE_GUID_ML & ";"

Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
Set rst = New ADODB.Recordset

With cn
    .ConnectionString = sConn
    .Open  '--> **HERE I GET THE ERROR**

End With

Rs = "SELECT * FROM [Template Library];"
rst.Open Rs, cn, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic
Do Until rst.EOF
    If Left(rst![Name], InStr(1, rst![Name], "#") - 1) = TemplateID Then
        NameFile = rst![Name]
        On Error GoTo Skip
        ActualVdate = rst![Validity Date]
        TransVdate = rst![Transition Period End]
        Exit Do
    Else
        rst.MoveNext
    End If
Loop
Skip:
rst.Close
```

The interesant part is that in DEBUG, if I use 12.0 first and then change to 16.0 and save, it will open it. Then, if I reopen file, i get same error.
Please help me guys.

Comment: Try 12.0. E.g. `Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0` See: https://www.connectionstrings.com/sharepoint/

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried to use 12.0, but I also have to install access database engine 2010 and access runtime 2010 in order to work. But this is not a solution because there are many computers and no AD to run a mass install. I have to make 16.0 work.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using VBA? If so, please ensure you have enabled the Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 6.1 Library on the reference menu.

Comment: Yes, it is enabled. Had you ever used OLEDB 16.0 ? Thanks

Comment: Try to put this code Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
Set rst = New ADODB.Recordset  before the NameFile = "x". Yes, I am using OLEDB 16.0.

Answer (score -2):

Try this;

cn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Ace.OLEDB.16.0;" & _
"Data Source=" & UserForm2.TextBox32.Text & ";Jet OLEDB:Database Password=1101010;Persist Security Info=False;"

Comment: Thanks for you answer! I tried your solution and still doesn't work. I get same error. Any other idea?